# How to correct ModuleNotFoundError for http.client

Tags: python, http, urllib, modulenotfounderror, http.client

I am trying to use the urllib library as part of a python program for web scraping. It contains the module request.py which has to import http.client. However I keep on getting this message:

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'http.client'; 'http' is not a package.

However, my Python libraries folder "Lib" contains both http folder and urllib folder. The http folder also contains client.py file. What could possibly be wrong? Please help I'm a beginner.

Comment: share the code please.

Answer (score 0):

Use the pip command as follows to install missing or old packages:

```
py -m pip install --upgrade http
```

You can also try uninstalling / reinstalling modules in hopes of fixing corrupted packages:

```
py -m pip uninstall http
py -m pip install --upgrade http
```

If all that doesn't work, try running a Command Prompt and running your file with the following command:

```
python file_name.py
```

Comment: I tried installing pip using get-pip.py but it also needs http.client as a module to complete installation.

Comment: Try reinstalling Python, and when installing make sure to check the "Install PIP" checkbox.

Answer (score 0):

In python you cannot override your packages.
You maybe have another module in your code called "http".
Just change it to "web" or any name you like and it should work.

This was an issue I had in my project.